# Mudar extensão de um ficheiro em C#

Tags: c#

Com um Openfiledialog estou a abrir um ficheiro, e quero que no Load, mude a extensão. Ou seja, eu vou coloquei que o "openFileDialog1.Filter" seria apenas para ".txt" e quero que mude para ".cnf".
Obrigado.

Comment: O que é *o Load*?

Comment: Não é no Load, é no Button @ramaral.

Comment: Não consigo perceber o que quer.

Answer (score 2):

Não sei o porque disto, mas uma solução simples é você fazer assim:

```
//aqui vai o caminho que você leu no OpenFileDialog
string caminho = "arquivo.txt";

//e aqui você cria uma variável que irá receber o novo caminho.
string novoCaminho = caminho.Remove(caminho.Length -3, 3) + "cnf";
```

Basicamente o que a linha acima faz é remover o `txt` do arquivo e adicionar o `cnf`;

Só que você vai ter que salvar o arquivo para ele ficar com está extensão.

Ou você pode usar uma função nativa do `C#`:

```
string caminhoPath = Path.ChangeExtension(caminho, ".cnf");
```

Veja mais sobre [Path.ChangeExtension()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.io.path.changeextension(v=vs.110).aspx).

[**Veja Funcionando**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/zp2eHQ)